# Jekyll collections with subdirectories and URL encoding spaces

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to accomplish the task of linking to files within a collection from a post on a Jekyll site. However, I'm having an issue that relates to the collection having subdirectories, and those subdirectories having spaces in their names.

Here's a simplified example of how my site source is layed out:

```
├── 404.html
├── about.md
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── index.md
├── _labs
│   └── Lab 01 Introduction
│       └── PS01 source.html
├── _posts
│   └── 2020-01-01-test_post.md
```

The post `2020-01-01-test_post.md` contains the following markdown:

```
---
layout: post
title: "Introduction"
author: "Will Hopper"
---

[Link]({{ site.baseurl }}{% link _labs/Lab 01 Introduction/PS01 source.html %})
```

So far so good, and running `jekyll serve` succeeds just fine, meaning it can find the linked file at build time. The issue arises later, with the way jekyll has handled the spaces in the `Lab 01 Introduction` directory. Here is the contents of the `_site` folder after building:

```
└── _site
    ├── 404.html
    ├── about
    │   └── index.html
    ├── assets
    │   ├── main.css
    │   └── minima-social-icons.svg
    ├── feed.xml
    ├── index.html
    ├── labs
    │   └── Lab%2001%20Introduction
    │       └── PS01 source.html
    └── posts
        └── test_post.html
```

As you can see, the spaces in the filename have been replaced with the URL encoded escapes, `%20`.  As a result, the link in the post 404's.

I tried replacing the "raw" name of the folder with the URL encoded output, i.e., I tried `{% link _labs/Lab%2001%20Introduction/PS01 source.html %}` but now the site fails to build with `Liquid Exception: Could not find document`.

This HTML file is effectively a static file (i.e., it has no front matter). And curiously, Jekyll seems to leave spaces in the filenames alone!

Any ideas on what I could do to stop the spaces in my directory names from being URL encoded when the site is built?